# Subscript out of range error in excel

Tags: vba, excel

Please assist with the code below, it gives an error of "subscript out of range" when I try running the code". When i debug, it highlight the portion below. Thanks in advance.

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename
Columns("A:AI").Copy
Windows("RealTime-APR").Activate
Sheets("Raw").Select
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```

Comment: 1) check whether you really have workbook with name "RealTime-APR" opened, 2) if yes, check whether your workbook "RealTime-APR" contains sheet with name "Raw"

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use `.Activate` ([INTERESTING READ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)) OR `.Copy/.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Try this

I am assuming that you have declared and set `Path` & `Filename`

```
Dim thisWb As Workbook, newWB As Workbook
Dim thisWs As Worksheet, newWs As Worksheet

Set thisWb = ThisWorkbook
Set thisWs = thisWb.Sheets("Sheet1")

Set newWB = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)
Set newWs = newWB.Sheets("RAW")

newWs.Columns("A:AI").Value = thisWs.Columns("A:AI").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Dim wbTarget as Workbook
ThisWorkbook.Columns("A:AI").Copy
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename
Set wbTarget = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
wbTarget.Activate
wbTarget.Sheets("Raw").Activate
wbTarget.Sheets("Raw").Range("YourTargetColumn e.g. A:A here").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

alternatively, use the `With statement:`

```
ThisWorkbook.Columns("A:AI").Copy
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename
With Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
    .Activate
    .Sheets("Raw").Activate
    .Sheets("Raw").Range("YourTargetColumn e.g. A:A here").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
```